# can't find difference between working and not working code

Tags: python

this is my second post here.
Why does summations calculator on one version of code running and in the second it doesnt

## documentation of program:

```
#Summations Calculator

#Create a program that takes 3 inputs, a lower bound, an upper bound and the expression. Calculate the sum of that range based on the given expression and output the result.

#For Example:
#Input: 2 4 *2
#Output: 18 (2*2 + 3*2 + 4*2)

#Input: 1 5 %2
#Output: 3 (1%2 + 2%2 + 3%2 + 4%2 + 5%2)
```

Working code:

```
def sum_calc(lowerBound,higherBound,expression):
 
    calcLine = "" # storage of final expression
   
    # for all num in range (unless the last) add number, expression and sign '+' to the line
    for num in range(int(lowerBound),int(higherBound)):
        calcLine += "{}{} + ".format(str(num),expression)
   
    # add last number with expression    
    calcLine += "{}{}".format(higherBound,expression)
   
    print(eval(calcLine),"({})".format(calcLine)) # evaluate the resulting line
 
   
 
## main block    
sum_calc(*input().split(" "))
```

and not working version: (I'm trying to rewrite it as a challenge)

```
def summCalc (lower, higher, expression):
    calcLine = "" # storage of final expression

    for num in range (int(lower),int(higher)):
        calcLine += "{}{} + ".format(str(num), expression)

    calcLine += "{}{} + ".format(higher, expression)

    print(eval(calcLine),"({})".format(calcLine)) # evaluate the resulting line

summCalc(*input().split(" "))
```

not working version shows **Unexpected EOF error**
[EOF error occurance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPTsO.png)

Comment: The code you are running through `eval()` and you did not show us is faulty.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN your code, below code

`calcLine += "{}{} + ".format(higher, expression)`

is adding etra `+` to the expression. ie  `calcLine = 1*2+2*2+3*2+`

now running `eval` on this expression with extra `+` will produce an error.

remove `+` from your expression and  make code as 
`calcLine += "{}{}".format(higher, expression)`

Answer (score 0):

It's syntax error. 
[image]

Just replace
`calcLine += "{}{} + ".format(higher, expression)` with `calcLine += "{}{}".format(higher, expression)`. The code should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

this code works when sugested change is providen

```
def summCalc (lower, higher, expression):
    calcLine = "" # storage of final expression

    for num in range (int(lower),int(higher)):
        calcLine += "{}{} + ".format(str(num), expression)

    calcLine += "{}{} ".format(higher, expression)

    print(eval(calcLine),"({})".format(calcLine)) # evaluate the resulting line

summCalc(*input().split(" "))
```